# Using an overflow for modulus with a signed integer

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing a bunch of different kinds of pseudo random number generators to play around with. I noticed that linear congruential generators can have periods the size of an int, and thought I could just use overflow instead of modulus and see if it's faster.

The only snag is that overflows overflow into the sign bit, and I need them all to be positive values.

EDIT: I was cloudy on a couple concepts, so I'm cleaning up this question so it makes more sense.
Basically it all boils down to me trying to lop off the sign bit of an integer. I've found that XORing the number with int.MinValue does the trick. But only when it has overflowed, if it hasn't that does the opposite. I'd like to avoid the extra if statement though.

If someone could show me some nifty trick to snag the first 31 bits and stuff them into an integer, that would be delightful. Or some way to just set the sign bit to zero would probably be better?

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to use `uint`?

Comment: Any reason not to test this yourself?

Comment: Yeah, the simulation I'm generating numbers for uses ints. And if I recall from other languages, uint uses the extra sign bit, so I'd guess you can't implicitly convert them to ints?

Comment: Msdn isn't much help eather and I can't check the return type 'Returns the absolute value of a specified number', because if it returns a decimal, you would have to cast it back to an int so you could already lose some (micro?)performance there.

Comment: int uses two's complement. When the sign bit is set, and all other bits are 0, the value is int.MinValue (i.e. -2147483648). There is no -0 for int.

Comment: @hatchet Oh riiight, I haven't done two's compliment in a while, I completely spaced. For some reason I was picturing the sign bit as a flip switch for positive or negative numbers. However, I could just XOR int.MinValue then, couldn't I? Basically I'm just trying to implement a 31 bit unsigned int that will fit nicely into an int

Comment: If your random number generator can return *any* integer (i.e. negative or positive), then just do your computation as `uint` and then cast to `int` on return. That is `return (int)uint_value;` That will work just fine. If you want to make sure that the number is not negative, there's no need to do an ABS. Just clear the sign bit: `return value & 0x7fffffff;` You might have to do that in an unchecked context.

Comment: Yeah I just came to the same conclusion, that what I was looking for was basically just a way of clearing the sign bit, but I did it by XORing the number with int.MinValue. Would your way of clearing the sign bit be faster?

Comment: XORing with `int.MinValue` toggles the sign bit. You don't want to do that if the number is positive. ANDing with `0x7fffffff` unconditionally clears the sign bit. With the AND, you don't have to check if the number is negative. So, yes, it would be faster.

Comment: ohhhh I'm not really that familliar with those values, I thought it was a memory address reference aha. I just came up with the same idea and realized it's exactly what you and hatchet were saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want overflow to start back at zero, you should just mask off the sign bit.

```
unchecked {
    int x = int.MaxValue + 5;
    int y = x & 0x7fffffff;
}
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

This outputs the number 4.

I don't think absolute value of the overflowed value will give you what you want (you would go up to maxint, and then descend back down, plus, you'll have to specially handle int.MaxValue + 1 because it equals int.MinValue, which Math.Abs() will throw an exception on).

```
unchecked {
    int x = int.MaxValue + 5;
    int y = Math.Abs(x);
}
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

This outputs the number 2147483644.

Comment: Yeah, I realized abs wouldn't work when you reminded me about two's complement. Thanks a bunch, that was the main thing that was throwing me.

Comment: I think you meant `int.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
int x = -100;

int mask = (x >> 31);
Trace.WriteLine((x + mask) ^ mask);

output: 100
```

Comment: But that can still come out negative

Comment: harold is right. This does not handle int.MinValue. This technique only works if you do this using uint operations, and return a uint.

Comment: with uint you don't need abs functions.